# SamlCredential does not retrieve group attributes from Okta SAML response

Tags: saml-2.0, spring-saml, okta, okta-api

I am using Okta as IDP and I have configured the user attribute statements and group attribute statements like this

[image]

And by providing a custom samluserdetails I am able to retrieve user attributes but not group attributes.

```
public class CustomSamlUserDetails implements SAMLUserDetailsService {
    @Override
    public Object loadUserBySAML(SAMLCredential cred) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        AppUser user = new AppUser();
        user.setFirstName(cred.getAttributeAsString("firstName"));
        user.setLastName(cred.getAttributeAsString("lastName"));
        user.setLoginId(cred.getAttributeAsString("loginId"));

        String groupname = cred.getAttributeAsString("role"); // comes null


        return user;
    }
}
```

Is there some config I missed or am I retrieving the group info in a wrong way?

**EDIT:**
If I use `contains` filter with some characters for example I have 3 groups **test1**, **test2** and **other1**. 
If I use `contains` filter *, I get null.
However if I use `contains` filter with **test** , I get **test1** (and **test2**, if user is path of both groups).
Is wildchar not supported in case of groups?
What if in above case user was part of all 3 groups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not an expert of OKTA but I statred working couple of weeks for one of my clients. I tested with * but it only worked for me for filter Regex. For other filters I never succeeded with *. For example the configuration without * worked perfectly for me.

[OKTA CONFIG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeyQk.png)

I used the code `String str = credential.getAttributeAsString("Groups");`

But I have one issue that when I have more then one group I still get one group. I want to have list of groups instead.

**EDIT - O6 Feb**

Finally I restested and I am able to implement wildcard entry with regex I used the regex filter :

[image: OKTA GROUP CONFIGURATION]

In java I got the groups as you suggested :

```
         String[] str = credential.getAttributeAsStringArray("groups");

     for(int i = 0; i< str.length; i++){
         System.out.println(str[i]);
     }
```

The result is :

[image: List of captured groups]

Have a great day

Comment: you can have a list of groups by using `getAttributeAsStringArray`. However the issue of getting all groups still remains. See my edit part in question.

Comment: Please have a look at my edited post. Hopefully this will solve your problem.